# Is it possible to collapse all the values that are a prefix of some other string into the super string within a PCollection?

Tags: apache-beam

Let's say I have a PCollection in java, and this can contain multiple strings like : "abc_def_ghi", "abc_def", "abc", "xyz" etc.
I want to collapse all the values that are a prefix of some other string into the super string, for example "abc_def" and "abc" are prefix of "abc_def_ghi", so they should be removed from this PCollection, is this possible to do?

This should be possible by using a global variable, perhaps a global hashmap, but that will be anti-pattern for beam pipeline.

Comment: Sounds like this can be done with https://beam.apache.org/documentation/basics/#aggregation